# htaccess url rewrite rule for blog

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, blogs

Hi I got an problem with my htaccess url rewirte rule i want to rewrite the following urls

`http://myhomepage.com/agb.html` to `http://myhomepage.com/agb`

and

`http://myhomepage.com//blog.php?archiv=webdesign-templates` to `http://myhomepage.com/blog/webdesign-templates`

this is my actual .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /blog/(.*) blog.php?archiv=$1

RewriteRule /kontakt kontakt.php
```

how to do this in the right way please need some help buddys.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a .htaccess already in `/blog/` directory?

Comment: No the htaccess is in the root directory

Comment: And there is no blog directory blog is the filename

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ blog.php?archiv=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/webdesign-templates/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ blog.php?archiv=webdesign-templates&titel=$1 [L, QSA]
RewriteRule ^kontakt$ kontakt.php [L, QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.html [L, QSA]
```

Comment: sorry how to rewrite the follwoing url too http://myhomepage.com//blog.php?archiv=webdesign-templates&titel=blogposttitel to http://myhomepage.com//blog/webdesign-templates/blogposttitel

Comment: @user1607143: Don't add a new question by comment. Edit your question.

Comment: @user1607143: I've added your request but please edit your question and add condition

Comment: hi not working i host my files on one.com but he gives me a 500 internal server error

Comment: Have you removed Options +FollowSymLinks from .htaccess?